# redirect output and log rotation

Tags: bash, cron, tcpdump

I need a bit of help with script / command / cronjob..

I need to redirect output of tcpdump command to logfile and keep 1 log file for each day. I know I could use tcpdump logging syntax but I'm also using `awk -F` to filter the output. 
My command looks like this and run by itself works beautifully.

`tcpdump -ieth0 -p "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) !=0" | awk -F 'Flags' '{print $1}' > /var/log/tcpdump.log`

How can I make it to rotate file for each day ? Is there any way to do with shell script (my shell scripting knowledge is very limited).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't good at shell scripting I wouldn't try to write your own log rotation.  It doesn't sound like you've got any need here that wouldn't be handled better by using [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) rather than rolling your own.  You can make a simple config file

```
# /etc/logrotate.d/tcpdump
"/var/log/tcpdump.log" {
       daily
       rotate 30
       compress

       prerotate
            killall your_dump_script
       endscript

       postrotate
            your_dump_script &
       endscript
 }
```

This will:

- rotate your file `daily`
- keep `30` copies around since you don't want to fill up your drive
- `compress` using gzip to save disk space.  You can use `zless` or `zgrep` to view them.
- kill `your_dump_script` before rotating and restart it after.  Feel free to rename this to something more to your liking.

If you put it in `/etc/logrotate.d` this should get picked up by your built-in cron jobs, but if you want to run it manually to verify that it works:

```
logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/tcpdump
```

Or put the config in a different location and run it in from your script.  Either way you're writing less code and things are more likely to work reliably.

Comment: Just yesterday I helped another senior ops engineer debug a script that was doing file rotation with bad date logic. It is easy to mess up and not realize it until "next year" when the code breaks.

Comment: If understood correctly - should I just run 'tcpdump > logfile |awk -F' to run in the background and use logrotate to rotate the logfiles ?

Comment: Yep.  If the tcpdump is always running then you will need to restart it too.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the code that should start and stop your process too.

Comment: Thanks ,I'll give it a try today. Should I just stick the tcpdump > logfile |awk -F' in a *.sh file and put into logrotate ?

Comment: Yes.  Having logratate run your script will make it easier to avoid issues with quoting.  It also makes it easier to test.

Comment: Hi chicks ,it's me again ;). I've got a problem with the script as logrotate doesn;t restart it . If I run the script ,the logrotate kills tcpdump but it doesn' start it again. I even changed the permissions to 777 to test it but it still the same.  
"/var/log/tcpdump/em2.log" {
       daily
       rotate 30
       compress

       prerotate
            killall tcpdump
       endscript

       postrotate
            /root/tables/logem2.sh & 
       endscript
 }

Comment: And here is script /root/tables/logem2.sh &  #!/bin/sh
tcpdump -iem2 -p "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) !=0" | awk -F 'Flags' '{print $1}' &> /var/log/tcpdump/em2.log &

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `rotatelogs` ([docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html)): all you need to do is pipe the output through it, provide few options and it will take care of the rest. For example:

```
tcpdump ... | rotatelogs /var/log/tcpdump.log
```

will automatically rotate the output file when your specified criteria (file size, time interval) are met.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [logrotee](https://github.com/singalen/logrotee) this weekend. I probably wouldn't if I've read @JdeBP's [great answer about `multilog`](https://superuser.com/a/291397/32412).

I focused on it being lightweight and being able to bzip2 its output chunks like:

```
verbosecommand | logrotee \
  --compress "bzip2 {}" --compress-suffix .bz2 \
  /var/log/verbosecommand.log
```

There's a lot of to be done and tested yet, though.